# Bootstrap 4 navbar horizontal overflow

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I would like to set up a horizontal navbar to scroll inside the page in the style of uber eats (https://www.ubereats.com/en-EN/new-york/food-delivery/zafis-luncheonette-les/-VDewOpIRMe4mh2tNVzVCw/ ,check the second navbar in which you can navigate throught the different categories of the menu). I managed to create the navbar and set the spyscroll but I don't know how to reproduce the responsive behaviour : how to hide the category from the navbar when it overflow and add it to the "More..." dropdown ?

I hope my question was clear enought !

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE] - a link to your website does not count - please read: [Something on my website doesn't work, can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1):

What You are looking for is called a "Priority Navigation". Just Google it, there are plenty of examples and plugins out there.
e.g. https://css-tricks.com/the-priority-navigation-pattern/ or http://gijsroge.github.io/priority-nav.js/